# Java pngquant on java not compiling into dll and jnilib

Tags: java, png, pngquant

I was trying to make libimagequant library work in java but I can't make the "dll" and can't make the "jnilib", I don't know why but it just doesn't work, if somebody could help it would be awesome.
I have already tried to make the "Makefile" but it gives me errors on errors, maybe someone already compiled a dll, I still don't understand why they don't pre build all the source.

EDIT NUM 1:
I would like to make the libimagequant library work in my java program,
I downloaded the library https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant
when i tried to run make Makefile java it gave me a message that touch is not recognized, as touch is not important i removed the command from Makefile, then i run it again and now it is giving me this error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, env bash C:\Users\Me\Desktop\libimag
equant\configure, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile'.
javah -o org/pngquant/LiqObject.h  org.pngquant.LiqObject
javac org/pngquant/PngQuant.java
javah -o org/pngquant/PngQuant.h  org.pngquant.PngQuant
javah -o org/pngquant/Image.h  org.pngquant.Image
javah -o org/pngquant/Result.h  org.pngquant.Result
make: *** No rule to make target `config.mk', needed by `pam.o'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Hey man, please.. we need as many details as possible. So, update your question in order to make it more understandable and complete with, of course, code samples about what you've already got. ;)

Comment: I added some details hope you can help :)